calling Blazor component with successive calls does not update the childComponents
I am learning Blazor and as a lesson, I am passing 2 variables to the component.
It is not updating for me.
I do not know why.
Each successive call should create a new component and add the values, but it does not seem to change the second value.  Trying to get the second value working first then I will add the first value, which is hard coded for now.
Thank you.
Component:
<div class="card" style="width: 4rem;">
    @*  <img class="card-img-top" src="@imageUrl" alt="Unit x" /> *@
    <div class="card-body">
        <h6 class="card-title">@Tactical</h6>
        <p class="card-text">@Assignment</p>
    </div>
</div>


@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Tactical { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Assignment { get; set; }
}

Index.razor:
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp1.Component

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
@{
    string name = "";
    string[] Assign = { "Sweep", "Rt35", "Rt48", "Rt100", "Rest E", "Cmd" };
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int a = 0;
    string b = "";
    @for(int x=0;x<3;x++) // Three rows
        {
        <div class="comp">
            @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // of 10 cards per row
            { 
                a = rnd.Next(0,5);
                b = Assign[a];

                <p>@b</p>
                <UnitComponent>
                    <Tactical>Sag-1</Tactical>
                    <Assignment>@b</Assignment>
                </UnitComponent>
            }
            <br />
            </div>
        }
    }
<div>End of Test</div>



I believe you just need to declare "b" inside the loop. Here's an example of it working: Blazor Fiddle Example

So it turns out in Razor syntax you cannot use a // for a comment. comments must be / / around the code to comment.  Also, the code needed some improvements:
Index.razor:
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp1.Component

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
@{
    string name = "";
    string[] Assign = { "Sweep", "Rt35", "Rt48", "Rt100", "Rest E", "Cmd" };
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int a = 0;
    string b = "";
    @for(int x=0;x<3;x++) // Three rows
        {
        <div class="comp">
            @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // of 10 cards per row
            { 
                a = rnd.Next(0,5);
                b = Assign[a];

                <p>@b</p>
                <UnitComponent Tactical="Sag-1" Assignment="@b">
                    @* <Tactical>Sag-1</Tactical>
                     <Assignment>@b</Assignment>*@
                </UnitComponent>
            }
            <br />
            </div>
        }
    }
<div>End of Test</div>

UnitComponent.razor:
<div class="card" style="width: 4rem;">    
    <div class="card-body">
        <h6 class="card-title">@Tactical</h6>
        <p class="card-text">@Assignment</p>
    </div>
</div>


@code {
    [Parameter] public string Tactical { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Assignment { get; set; }
}

